# NSURLSession file transfer restarted?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I am using `NSURLSession` for uploading a file with background transfer service, but after uploading few bytes. `NSURLSession` starts upload again, Don't know exactly why `NSURLSession` restart and send the same bytes to the server which are already uploaded.

Comment: You might check for either redirect or authentication challenge.

Comment: we have multiple nsurlsession instance with multiple files. But this problem is happening with few instance only. Others are uploading successfully.

Comment: I also encounter the same problem when the upload file size is large. I guess there is something breaking with the server when a large file is sent. Check the maximum upload file size limit the server has. 
__Upload and download tasks in background sessions are automatically retried by the URL loading system after network errors. It is unnecessary to use reachability APIs to determine when to retry a failed task.__
Source: [URL Session Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html)